# Apply VBA macro to subsequent rows

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to clear the contents of some cells if the value in a corresponding cell changes.

In the code below, if the value in O1 changes, the contents of Z1 to AD1, and P1 are cleared.
How can I apply this to all rows below, i.e. if O2 changes, the contents of Z2 to AD2, and P2 should be cleared, the same thing for row 3 and so on.

I'd like if new columns/rows are inserted in the worksheet, things won't break.

```vb
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    
    If Target.Address = "O1" Then    
        Range("Z1:AD1").ClearContents
        Range("P1").ClearContents
    End If
    
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

This should get you started

1. Only looks for changes that occur in `Column O`
2. Only triggers if **ONE** cell is changed at a time.
   *(you will need to switch to loop if many cells in `Column O` can be changed in one action such as pasting a range)*
3. Be sure to turn events **OFF** before making any other changes to worksheet else you will end up in infinite loop leading to your instance of excel crashing
4. Make dynamic by clearing cells that are on the same row as the changed cell i.e. `Target.Row`

---

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

If Not Intersect(Target, Range("O:O")) Is Nothing Then
    If Target.Count = 1 Then
        Application.EnableEvents = False
        
            Range(Cells(Target.Row, "Z"), Cells(Target.Row, "AD")).ClearContents
            Cells(Target.Row, "P").ClearContents
            
        Application.EnableEvents = True
    End If
End If

End Sub
```

Comment: This worked flawlessly. Thank you so much!!

Answer (score 0):

This should work.

```
    Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

        tCol = Target.Column
        tRow = Target.Row
        If tCol = 15 Then
            For i = tRow To tRow + Target.Rows.Count - 1
                Range(Cells(i, 26), Cells(i, 30)).ClearContents
                Cells(i, 16).ClearContents
            Next
        End If
    End Sub
```

Use Target.Column and Target.Row to get the number of the targets column and row which can then be used in Cells().